# Maximal Ideal of Subring of K[x,y]

Tags: polynomials, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I came across the subring $S=K[x,xy,xy^2,\ldots]$ of $R=K[x,y]$ (where $K$ is a field) in a book about commutative algebra.

The author claims that the ideal $I=(x,xy,xy^2,\ldots)$ is maximal in $S$.

I wanted to understand this statement for myself. I can see why it is true, but I am looking for a rigorous way to explain this.

My first thought was to construct a homomorphism $S\rightarrow K$ and then apply the first isomorphism theorem. However, I am not sure how this homomorphism looks like.

Any hints or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: What about the homomorphism $S\to K$ sending $k\mapsto k$ for $k\in K$ and $xy^i\mapsto 0$? I.e. every polynomial is identified with its constant term.

Comment: Is the kernel of this homomorphism the ideal $I$? Sorry, but I am not sure how to see this.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Let me lay out some basics in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us consider $K[x,y]$ first. For a ring homomorphism $K[x,y]\to K$, we would like it to be as natural as possible, and so would like to send $k\mapsto k$ for $k\in K$. This actually means we are looking at a $K$-algebra homomorphism, but that is not important.

Note that $K[x,y]$ is generated over $K$ as a ring by the elements $1,x,y$. It is now a result that for any choice of of elements $k_1,k_2$, there is a unique ring homomorphism $\phi:K[x,y]\to K$ where $\phi(k)=k$, $\phi(x)=k_1$ and $\phi(y)=k_2$. This is not hard to prove, think of it like how a linear map acts on a basis of a vector space. How it acts on all other elements are uniquely determined by being a ring homomorphism, i.e. respecting addition and multiplication.

Picking $k_1=k_2=0$ then gives us a legitimate homomorphism, which must have kernel containing $x$ and $y$, thus, as the kernel is an ideal, it must contain $(x,y)$. It does not contain any polynomial with a non-zero constant coefficient though, as $k\mapsto k$, so this ideal must be the entire kernel.

All this also works for your $S$. In particular, you can just map $S$ into $K[x,y]$ by inclusion and then use the map just described. You will then see that the kernel is exactly $(x,xy,xy^2,\dots)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailled explanation. Now, I see it more clearly. I really appreciate your help and effort.